# Create Agent Database for Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to build an internal App through Google App Maker to track Sales Agents stats. The idea is to pull the data from a Google Sheet where I will have everything to be viewed.

The Fields necessary will be:

- Domain
- Agent
- Users
- Status

Each agent will have their own PAGE with their name and DATA which imports from the sheet containing only their information. I tried creating one "John" and moved all his data in "Sheet2" from the Database "Sheet1".

**Pictures of the sheet where it's pulling the data**
[image: Pictures of the sheet where it's pulling the data]

**A screen of the Google App Maker setup and error in the console**
[image: A screen of the AppMaker setup and error in the console]

Running the App gives the following error when running it:

```
Invalid binding path: @datasource.item.Status in Sheet2.Table1Panel.Table1.Table1Body.Table1Row$13.Field
```

Comment: Seems you are not using the proper datasource. Make sure that you are using a datasource from the model named "John"

Comment: Yes, I guess that got it fixed. Thanks !